# IE support for multiple Angular ng-class expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have a code sample below where i check for file extension and accordingly set the icon for uploaded file. As there is support for multiple files, i have set icon for each of them and based on extension i apply related class with `ng-class` attribute. Its not working in IE11. I checked with single expression to confirm and it worked. Is there a workaround to this?

```
<i flex ng-class="{
          'icon-pdf': (fileDetails['extention'].search('pdf') != -1),
          'icon-word': (fileDetails['extention'].search('doc') != -1),
          'icon-ppt': (fileDetails['extention'].search('ppt') != -1),
          'icon-xls': (fileDetails['extention'].search('xlsx') != -1),
          'icon-html': (fileDetails['extention'].search('html') != -1),
          'icon-jpg': (fileDetails['extention'].search('jpg') != -1),
                        'icon-jpg': (fileDetails['extention'].search('png') != -1),
          'icon-wit': (fileDetails['extention'].search('txt') != -1)}"
>
            </i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read about this bug before but you could create a function that returns the proper class instead of having multiple `ng-class` attributes like so:

In your template:

```
<i flex ng-class="getIconClass(fileDetails['extention'].search)"></i>
```

And in your controller:

```
function getIconClass(search) {
    if(search('pdf') != -1)
        return 'icon-pdf';
    if(search('doc') != -1)
        return 'icon-word';
    if(search('ppt') != -1)
        return 'icon-ppt';
    if(search('xlsx') != -1)
        return 'icon-xls';
    if(search('html') != -1)
        return 'icon-html';
    if(search('jpg') != -1 || search('png') != -1)
        return 'icon-jpg';
    if(search('txt') != -1)
        return 'icon-wit';
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems the cleaner approach. I also found out a way, posted in the below answer, maybe helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way of doing it, using `ng-class` ternary operator besides Martijn's way (which is cleaner). Posting it for sake of expanding knowledge.

```
<i flex ng-class="
    fileDetails['extention'].search('pdf') != -1? 'icon-pdf': 
    fileDetails['extention'].search('doc') != -1 ? 'icon-word': 
    fileDetails['extention'].search('ppt') != -1? 'icon-ppt':
    fileDetails['extention'].search('xlsx') != -1? 'icon-xls':
    fileDetails['extention'].search('html') != -1? 'icon-html':
    fileDetails['extention'].search('jpg') != -1? 'icon-jpg':
    fileDetails['extention'].search('png') != -1? 'icon-jpg':
    fileDetails['extention'].search('txt') != -1? 'icon-wit': 'icon-html' "></i>
```